# pigpio gpioHardwareClock() and gpioSetAlertFunc() does not activate on my second pi 4

Tags: gpio, pi-4, pigpio

So Im moving my code to a new pi4 from my old pi4 because i think the old one has some hardware problems. but when i ran my code on the pi 4 two of the functions that i heavily rely on does not work anymore these two functions from the pigpio library

***gpioHardwareClock()*** - So the behaivor is very odd because when i ran gpioHardwareclock() on any of the clock supported pins it does nothing. So i tried starting the hardware clock using a different code and it does turn on so i know its not broken. And when i ran gpioHardwareclock() on a pin that already running a harwareclock it actually turns the clock off.

***gpioSetAlertFunc()*** - As for this one it just simply does not work. It does not capture the state changes

I even went as far as swapping the SD card of both pi to see if im not crazy, both identical code (but on different sd card) was able to output a clock on the old pi, and both sd card is not able to output a clock on the newer pi even though the newer pi is totally capable of outputting a clock. The pigpio library are not throwing errors when executing both of those functions.

**Test Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>

int main(){

    int error_code;

    error_code = gpioInitialise();
    printf("Initialise: %d\n", error_code);

    error_code = gpioHardwareClock(4,5000000);
    printf("Clock0: %d\n", error_code);

    error_code = gpioHardwareClock(5,5000000);
    printf("Clock1: %d\n", error_code);

    error_code = gpioHardwareClock(6,5000000);
    printf("Clock2: %d\n", error_code);

}
```

**Executed by**

```
$ gcc -o main main.c -lpigpio
$ sudo ./main
```

**Prints**

```
Initialise: 79
Clock0: 0
2021-03-24 04:48:37 gpioHardwareClock: Need password to use clock 1 (5)
Clock1: -99
Clock2: 0
```

Hardware and versions

```
old pi 4
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Hardware    : BCM2711
Revision    : c03111
Serial      : 10000000e1b06f41
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1

New Pi 4
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo    

Hardware    : BCM2711
Revision    : c03111
Serial      : 100000002b794a51
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1


$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:33:35 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ pigpiod -v
79
```

I have managed to somehow make clock 0 (GPIO4) to work normally and im not sure what i did. Clock 2 how ever remains not functioning.

[image]

heres proof that clock2 does indeed works. The code i used to run clock2 is fairly long so wont post it, but if you need it ill post it here

[image]

after running the test code again with clock 2 running, it will turn clock2 off

```
Initialise: 79
Clock0: 0
2021-03-24 05:07:30 gpioHardwareClock: Need password to use clock 1 (5)
Clock1: -99
Clock2: 0
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a small but complete code example as a program we can compile and run to see the problem.  Please also provide details of the operating system and pigpio versions.

Comment: @joan i have updated the question, please check it out.